# Compactness of the moduli space of representations of fundamental group

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, representation-theory, fundamental-groups, gauge-theory

Let $M$ be a compact manifold and $G$ a compact Lie group. I am trying to deduce that the moduli space of flat connections on $M$ is compact, and for that I have shown that there is a correspondence between flat $G$-connections modulo gauge equivalence and equivalence classes of representations of the fundamental group of $M$, but now I can't see why this space of representations is compact.

I do not have much background in representation theory or algebraic topology, so I am mostly looking for a reference for this result. If this is something that should be clear from more basic results (if I had the background), a sketch of the proof would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I'm assuming $M$ is connected; the disconnected case is not much more complicated since there are only finitely many connected components. Also, presumably $M$ is a smooth manifold here so you can talk about flat connections.)

The moduli space of flat connections is $\text{Hom}(\pi_1(M), G)/G$ (quotienting by the conjugation action of $G$). $\text{Hom}(\pi_1(M), G)$ is a closed subspace of $G^{\pi_1(M)}$ (cut out by the axioms of a homomorphism) which is compact Hausdorff by Tychonoff's theorem, so $\text{Hom}(\pi_1(M), G)$ is also compact Hausdorff. Hence its quotient by the conjugation action of $G$ is also compact (but not necessarily Hausdorff).

As far as I can tell, this argument does not require that $M$ is compact. If $M$ is compact we learn more, though: in that case $\pi_1(M)$ is finitely presented so $\text{Hom}(\pi_1(M), G)$ can be cut out of a finite product of copies of $G$ by a finite number of relations, and we learn that the moduli space of flat connections is "finite-dimensional" and even "algebraic" in a suitable sense.

This follows, for example, from the fact that compact manifolds have the homotopy type of finite CW complexes (which in particular have finitely many $0$-cells, $1$-cells, and $2$-cells); see, for example, [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/36838/are-non-pl-manifolds-cw-complexes). For compact smooth manifolds we can instead use [Morse theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_theory) but I'm not sure what the precise statements are.

Comment: Yes, it is a smooth manifold. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan, The above argument shows that the moduli space is compact in the topology of $\text{Hom}(\pi_1(M), G)$. I am interested in a slightly different view point: fix a manifold $M$ and a bundle $P$. Suppose $A_\nu$ is a sequence of smooth flat connections. Can we say there is a subsequence which converges? There are two choices of topologies (i) $A_\nu \in A_0 + C^{\infty}(M; T^*M\otimes  \mathfrak{g}_P)$  and (ii) $A_\nu \in A_0 + W^{1,p}(M; T^*M\otimes  \mathfrak{g}_P)$.

Comment: In one line, is the map from $\text{Hom}(\pi_1(M), G)/G$ to $C^{\infty}(M; T^*M\otimes  \mathfrak{g}_P)$ continuous?